# React project getting error when adding new pdf to shared PDF file

Tags: reactjs, pdf, frontend, react-pdf

I have a shared file where I outline all my PDFs that show.

```
{
    id: 90,
    classId: 9,
    detail: "AWS Fundementals",
    cert: "/assets/images/certs1/AWS_fundamentals.pdf",
},
{
    id: 91,
    classId: 9,
    detail: "How to buy cloud",
    cert: "/assets/images/certs1/how_to_buy_cloud.pdf",
},
{
    id: 92,
    classId: 9,
    detail: "AWS boto3",
    cert: "/assets/images/certs1/aws_boto3_s3.pdf"
},
```

ID 90 and 91 render just fine, but when I add the cert path to ID 92, I get

```
Unhandled Rejection (InvalidPDFException): Invalid PDF structure
```

If I just removed the path so it's like this

```
{
    id: 92,
    classId: 9,
    detail: "AWS boto3"
}
```

It will render the page exactly like it's supposed to. All the PDFs render fine. Just when I add the path for the new PDF it throws the error.

Here is my `RenderCert` function:

```
import PDF from "react-pdf-js";

function RenderCert({details}) {
    if (details.cert != null)
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <Card>
                        <PDF file={details.cert} />
                    </Card>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    else 
        return(
            <div>{details.name}</div>
        );
}
```

Any advice is appreciated. And let me know if I need to share more of the code to help troubleshoot. JS is still very new to me.

Comment: If i put any other PDF into that 92 slot it works. If I put the PDF in question into slot 90, it fails. Is there some reason this specific PDF would not be able to be used? Some kind of corruption?

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to fix the issue by downloading the PDF onto my windows computer which is about a year old, then transferring it via flash drive to my linux computer, about 3 months old.